# QTCreator Call Hierarchy

Tags: c, qt-creator

Do someone know how to see the call hierarchy (when coding in C, similar to the one that Eclipse has) in QTCreator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creator does not have that feature yet. If you want to know who is using your function you can use "Find Usages" though.

Contributions are -- as with all open source projects -- welcome;-)

Comment: @barakc, Eclipse CDT has that feature.

Comment: This is a post since 2012, is it still not implemented? I know you can see the call tree when debugging, it could be easily be provided without debugging.

Comment: The feature is Still not implemented :-); and they still welcome :-)

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11660 Seems to have been resolved 2 months ago ?